# Adding CSS-classes to HTML-tags After Retrieving Them From Database

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

For my blog, I want to be able to add css-classes to html-tags when I retrieve them from the DB.

For example, I have in the following in my DB, in a column called `body`:

```
<p>
    SO is great
</p>
```

Then I output it in the View, with sth like this:

`{{ blogpost.body }}`

But what I actually want to have is this:

```
<p class="class1 class2 class3">
    SO is great
</p>
```

How can I do this?

I can only think of using JS and adding the classes but I don't like this idea.

Is there maybe a way to pre-format it and save it ready in the DB? Or is this a bad practice?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why you dont like the JS option?

Comment: p tags arrives like a string?

Comment: it seems to me that you are already using html in your database so using classes in your DB is not going to harm anything. In fact thats how a lot of custom Wordpress, and php plugins work.

Comment: @fuzzybaird OK. How should I go about it? Would you like to create an answer about this?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It would slow down the loading a bit. Also I would like to find a cleaner solution (at least cleaner in my opinion) but if you think this is the correct way to go, please feel free to create an answer explaining this and I would be happy to test it out.

Comment: @Mr.Bruno What else could it arrive as?

Answer (score 1):

So instead of

```
 SELECT body
```

can you try:

```
SELECT REPLACE (body, '<p>', '<p class="class1 class2 class3">') as body
```

OR UPDATE in your db

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET body = REPLACE (body, '<p>', '<p class="class1 class2 class3">')
WHERE body LIKE '<p>%'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My objection is that such a query would be unreadable (imagine doing this for every html-element). I think a better option would be to modify the body before inserting it into the DB.

Comment: Check update version, of course you have to expand it. But you can make it a function

Answer (score 0):

Can you put it in a container?

```
<div class="{{ blogpost.tags }}">
    {{ blogpost.body }}
</div>
```